# DataPower: DNS lookup is failing

Tags: ibm-datapower

So far,  we were using the IP (198.x.x.1) to connect to LDAP from DataPower in ISAM config file, now when I changed the IP to the hostname ( d1-ldap), I found that DatPower is not able to connect to LDAP.

DataPower is not able to resolve this hostname and DNS lookup is failing.

However, when I configured the host alias ( 198.x.x.1 = d1-ldap), the connection has established succesfully. Can DataPower not connect to any host using its hostname if we dont configure the host aliases?

Regards,

Rahul

Answer (score 2):

Did you configure DNS on the DataPower appliance? If yes, can you connect to the port using a "test tcp-connection"? (or the equivalent in the WebGUI). When you try to ping from DataPower, can you see the DNS name being resolved to the IP address that you would expect?

Good luck!

Johan Thole (IBM)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to establish a connection first check firewall rules and do a connection test like TCP. According to my understanding you need to create a SSL SNI Server Profile to establish a successful hand shake.